# How to copy / move data from AWS EBS to EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, aws-ebs

I've mostly found old answers and I'm not sure I understand the AWS guide.

The AWS guide for some reason assumes I have an NFS server as source. Other people suggest simply mounting EBS and EFS and using a simple "cp" command. Unfortunately that's very slow.

What's the fastest way of moving data from EBS to EFS?
Is EFS File Sync the right option?

*Old answers suggesting simple cp command*

[AWS switch from EBS to EFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797846/aws-switch-from-ebs-to-efs)

[AWS EBS Snapshot to EFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125563/aws-ebs-snapshot-to-efs)

*File Sync Guide assuming NFS*

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/walkthrough-file-sync-ec2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to support and the File Sync tool only makes sense for existing NFS servers.

You may run into problems with burst credits on the EFS, depending on how much you migrate. For me it seems like a long running rsync is the best option. There is no better way to do this.